# How to count number of 1s without using an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, comparison

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int m, count = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Limit : ");
    m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] a = new int[m];
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Numbers :");

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    foreach (int o in a)
    {
        if (o == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Number of 1s in the Entered Number : "+count);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

here get each value into the array, and check each value equal to one are not. But i need this task without using an array. Could you please help us.

Comment: What do you  mean "without using an array"?  How else do you imagine it would work, in your case?  Where would you store the input, other than in a collection (array, list etc.).  What exactly is your issue here?

Comment: Are you happy if we show you a list solution?

Comment: Your question is very unclaer. In your GUI user can enter `m` different numbers, for example `1` but also `12` or even `111`. So even with just *one* single number the count of `1` could be far greater 1. So are you looking for *all* the `1` in *all* numbers, or just limit the user entering one single digit per number, meaning only numbers from 0 to 9? In other words: what happens if your user enters `2` for `m` and then `1234` and `1111` for the actual numbers? Would the output be `2` or `5`?

Answer (score 4):

Just check the input when it's entered, without storing it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            int m, count = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Limit : ");
            m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Numbers :");

            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
              if(Console.ReadLine() == "1")
                 count++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Number of 1's in the Entered Number : "+count);

            Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply keep a count where you add it to the array

```
        int m, count = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Limit : ");
        m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Numbers :");
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
           count += Console.ReadLine() == "1" ? 1 : 0;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Number of 1's in the Entered Number : "+count);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ and remove the `for` loop as well as the array.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the Limit : ");
int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the Numbers :");

int count =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, m)
        .Select(n => Console.ReadLine())
        .Where(x => x == "1")
        .Count();

Console.WriteLine("Number of 1's in the Entered Number : " + count);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

I would advice using more meaningful variable names and adding input validation `Int32.TryParse` instead `Convert.ToInt32`.

Just do the `if (o == 1)` check in the first `for` and forget about the second one.

Answer (score -1):

You can use List instead of array.
code is here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NumberofOnes
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int m, count = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Limit : ");
            m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            List<int> a = new List<int>();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Numbers :");
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                a.Add( Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
            foreach (int o in a)
            {
                if (o == 1)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Number of 1's in the Entered Number : " + count);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```